# Android: stop services and alarms when the application ends

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have an application that consist of several Activities.  When the application starts, some alarms are scheduled using `AlarmManager` and some services are started:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
a.setInexactRepeating(...)
....
```

I would like to know any way to **guarantee every service is stopped and every alarm is unscheduled when the user exits the application**.

The problem is that the user can leave the application from different Activities, and  I don't like the idea of overriding the `onDestroy` method in every Activity.  Is there any known `Intent` I can receive when the application ends?

I've also found that an Android application can have a class that extends from `Application`, with a `onTerminate` method:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application { 
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        ...
    }
}
```

But the documentation is very clear: *"never depend on this method being called; in many cases an unneeded application process will simply be killed by the kernel without executing any application code"*

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know any way to
>   guarantee every service is stopped and
>   every alarm is unscheduled when the
>   user exits the application.

There is no such thing as "user exits the application" in Android.

> Is there any known Intent I can
>   receive when the application ends?

No.

> I've also found that an Android
>   application can have a class that
>   extends from Application, with a
>   onTerminate method

This will be called, in many cases, sometime after there are no more running components. In your case, there are running components (services).

> But the documentation is very clear:
>   "never depend on this method being
>   called; in many cases an unneeded
>   application process will simply be
>   killed by the kernel without executing
>   any application code"

The only case I know of when it will not be called is if the process is being terminated, in which case your service will be eliminated as well, though scheduled alarms will not.